# how do I update list in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

> *I want to update the data in list and pass to next activity*

```
holder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
redeemQuantityModel.setQuantity(redeemQuantityModel.getQuantity()+1);
quantity++;
price = price + redeemQuantityModel.getPrice();
                       redeemQuantityModel.setPrice(redeemQuantityModel.getPrice());
                             Log.d("price", "onClick: "+price);
                             Log.d("model_price", "onClick: "+redeemQuantityModel.getPrice());
                             increementInterface.onClick(v,i,quantity,price);
                             notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
```

how to i update price of cart when user click increment and pass data  this is my activity where i nee to update my list.

Comment: where are you setting the recyclerview ?

Comment: In activity and i passed the list to B activity but the price is no updating can you help me to solve this

Comment: post your activity code where from you want to update you list of recyclerview

Comment: where do i post new Question.??? here comment section.??

Comment: you have to edit your question